# How is it possible for DAX syntax to reference the original table name when using table variables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

This question comes from an example that I'm trying to understand in [The Definitive Guide to DAX, Second Edition](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/definitive-guide-to-dax-business-intelligence-for-microsoft-9781509306978) chapter 4. If you want the sample Power BI file, you can download it from the website above; it's Figure 4-26 in chapter 4. Here is the DAX code:

```
Correct Average = 
VAR CustomersAge =
    SUMMARIZE (                -- Existing combinations
        Sales,                 -- that exist in Sales
        Sales[CustomerKey],    -- of the customer key and 
        Sales[Customer Age]    -- the customer age
    ) 
RETURN
AVERAGEX (                     -- Iterate on list of
    CustomersAge,              -- Customers/age in Sales
    Sales[Customer Age]        -- and average the customer’s age
)
```

I understand the logic behind how `SUMMARIZE` and `AVERAGEX` are used in this example, and the requirements are all clear. What's confusing to me is *how `AVERAGEX` references `Sales[Customer Age]`*. Since `AVERAGEX` is operating on the *summarized* `CustomersAge` table variable, I would have assumed that the syntax would have been something along the lines of:

```
AVERAGEX (
    CustomersAge,
    [Customer Age]             -- This is the line that I assumed would be different
)
```

How is it that the code given in the book is correct? Does the table variable (and the summarized table it contains) somehow have pointers to the original underlying table and column names? And is that normal for writing DAX queries, to always reference the original underlying table and column names when using table variables for intermediate steps?

Comment: For each  [CustomerKey] you have a unique [Customer Age]. Summarize just makes a table with "distinct" values. Summarize() saves linkage and Average works like `AVERAGEX (CustomersAge,CULCULATE(Sales[Customer Age]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the columns have what's known as data lineage. Sometimes you even have to restore lineage if it gets lost. You can read more about it here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-data-lineage-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic -- and I particularly appreciate that the article you linked to is by one of the authors of the book. :) I'll have to learn more about data lineage. The book doesn't get there until chapters 10 and 14, according to the index.

Comment: You're welcome. There are lots of hidden features in DAX. Just prepare yourself for when you get to auto-exists as that won't be pleasant reading ;).

Answer (score 1):

Lars, To the best of my understanding this is how I can explain it.

Creating a variable doesn't create a table that is added to the model. You can think of variables as steps or placeholders of a series of DAX expressions.

And so in the case of the SUMMARIZE used in the CustomerAge variable in this code, you'd see that the actual columns in the model were what was referenced in the arguments of SUMMARIZE. So when you perform calculations on that variable, the columns you can access are the actual columns in the model rather new columns.

What the variable has done is to help you break down the process of writing the calculation and make it less complex.

The code you wrote, as what you expect, would have been valid if in the CustomerAge variable, we created a new column, say Age * 2, and needed to perform the average over that. Then in that case that new column isn't part of the model, thus we'd reference it like you wrote.

I just got my copy of the book but I hope this helps a bit.